# TreeNode select() does not call select listener

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I use the following code to get a sap.ui.commons.TreeNode and to select it.

```
var newNode = this.tree.getNodes()[typeIdx].getNodes()[typeArray.length - 1];
newNode.select();
```

Unfortunately though, nothing happens. While `newNode.getIsSelected()` returns true, no handlers are executed (neither select on the tree nor selected on the node).

P.S. I made sure `newNode.getSelectable()` is true.

Did anyone use TreeNode's select() method sucessfully?

**Code example**

[Here is an example](http://jsbin.com/hososexu/3/edit?html,output)

Adding an element does highlight the element but the alert is only shown when clicking with the mouse.

Comment: Can you share an example where this is not working?In this example it works for me: http://jsbin.com/ninutora/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how this works.

Here's the function that we want to call on the node selection:

```
var sel = function(oEvent) {
    console.log(oEvent.getSource().getText() + " selected");
};
```

And here's the tree with some nodes, nodes 1.1 and 1.2 have the handler:

```
new sap.ui.commons.Tree("tree", {
    nodes: [
        new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode({
            text: "1",
            nodes: [
                new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode({
                    text: "1.1",
                    selected: sel
                }),
                new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode({
                    text: "1.2",
                    selected: sel
                })
            ]
        }),
        new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode({
            text: "2"
        })
    ]
}).placeAt("content");
```

And when we do this (based on your example):

```
newNode = sap.ui.getCore().byId("tree").getNodes()[0].getNodes()[0]
newNode.select()
```

we get

```
1.1 selected
```

in the console, and the the node is highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `newNode.setIsSelected(true);` That works for me

Best,
Robin

Answer (score 1):

Having read the exact requirement (the event `onSelect` not being fired), I think there were two things missing:

1. the `fireSelected` event was not explicitly fired
2. the `select` event was set on the *Tree* element rather than the *TreeNode* template

I have updated your example to a new version: http://jsbin.com/hososexu/7/edit

Comment: [Select](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.Tree.html#event:select) is fired by a Tree whenever one of its nodes gets selected.

Your manual call to fireSelected invokes the selected handler but not the tree's select handler. On the other hand, your example provides a hint at what might be the problem. When your alert is shown, the tree is completely empty. It seems the new nodes for the updated model are not yet visible and will probably not fire events as well.

Comment: You could be right, but logically it makes more sense (to me at least ;-) to use the `selected` event of the particular TreeNode rather than the `select` event of the Tree